# First time jQuery $.post takes an extraordinarily long time, subsequent times normal

Tags: ajax, performance, jquery, jquery-post

On a webpage we have the following system of server side form validation. For example, if the user is adding date-details for an event (and an event can contain many such date-details), we call a javascript function on click of the 'Add' button like below.

```
validateForm('frmName','codelibrary/classes/myclass.php','validationArrName')
where:
@frmName = form name
@codelibrary/classes/myclass.php = location of class file, that contains classes and functions for server side validation
@validationArrName = Type of validation we apply

In the php script, validationArrName is defined as a list of keys (representing form fields) and values (representing the functions we will call to validate that form field).
validationArrName  = array ('fieldName1'=>validationFun1,'fieldName2'=>validationFun2);

eg:
fieldName1 = email_address
validationFun1 = validateEmail()
```

On the html page, we call the server side validation through ajax as follows.

```
$.post(className,$("form[name="+formName+"]").serialize()+"&isValidate=1&validateArrayName="+validateArrayName,function(data){ ... });
```

If the validation function reports an error, we display an appropriate error message back on the html page.

The problem is that when we do this for the very first time (eg: after a hard refresh of the page), submitting this date-details form for validation takes **a lot** of time, as compared to subsequent requests.

We observed that instead of calling the codelibrary/classes/myclass.php file once, it actually refers to this file more than 10 times before jumping to the required location (validationArrName) and running that.

For subsequent requests, it works fine and refers to that file only once.

What could be the issue here? Could there be an issue with our usage of jquery submit ?

Comment: I don't get something straight, you say that there 10 ajax calls the first time, or that there is 10 calls to the myclass.php from your server?

Comment: 10 calls to the myclass.php on the server, however the validationArrName portion isnt called/accessed until the last call.

Comment: Hi @roselan - there are 10 calls to the myclass.php on the server, however the validationArrName portion isnt called/accessed until the last call...

Comment: I edited my answer, the point is it's quite hard to understand what happens with the information/code you provided. A more comprehensive code would help, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing you can do is time stuff.

in javascript:

```
console.time('post load'):
$.post(className,$("form[name="+formName+"]").serialize()+"&isValidate=1&validateArrayName="+validateArrayName,function(data){ 
    console.timeEnd('post load');
    console.log('data');
    ... 
});
```

in php, use microtime to time different part and echo them. they will be printed in the console.

It should not be cache or include related, as ajax starts a new connection each time.

Following your comments, I edit this answer:

I'm still at loss of what happens. However I see two possibilities. The first one is that you use a "flag" to validate forms or not. When you load the page, all forms flag are unset, and first submit check them all. Subsequent submits works correctly.

Another option is that the first time you submit a form, you dont `event.preventDefault()` on the submit click, but it's still a loosy explanation.

I would love to see how you call the `$.post(...)` function (how the submit button is binded, or how $().submit() is called).